# How to compile chromium with additional flags?

Tags: c++, chromium, clang++, instrumentation, ldflags

I am going to instrument Chromium. So, after adding some tracepoints, I have to add some additional flags during compilation of Chromium but I do not know where I should add them exactly! Do you have any idea how I can compile chromium with the debugging flag for chromium?

Thanks

Comment: You should modify ``args.gn`` file and set ``is_debug = true`` in that file then it will compile debug version of Chromium

Answer (score 1):

To get Chromium to respect custom `CXX`, `CXXFLAGS`, `LDFLAGS` etc. settings, whether for instrumentation or for any other flags you wish to add, override the toolchain.

Quoting from https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/build/toolchain/linux/unbundle/:

> **Usage**
>
> Add the following to GN args:
>
> ```
> custom_toolchain="//build/toolchain/linux/unbundle:default"
> host_toolchain="//build/toolchain/linux/unbundle:default"
> ```
>
> See [more docs on GN](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/tools/gn/docs/quick_start.md).
>
> To cross-compile (not fully tested), add the following:
>
> ```
> host_toolchain="//build/toolchain/linux/unbundle:host"
> v8_snapshot_toolchain="//build/toolchain/linux/unbundle:host"
> ```
>
> Note: when cross-compiling for a 32-bit target, a matching 32-bit toolchain may be needed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have a C file as well as a header file. I want to use one of my functions in some parts of built-in code. I would like to know where I should add my header and C file to compile by ninja. Additionally, if I want to add some flags (LDFLAGS) which are needed by compiler, where should I add them so that the compiler uses them?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @user32557 That's a different question and something I don't know about, sorry. The easiest way to figure it out would probably be to look through the Chromium source history (I'm asusming you cloned it already anyway), find some recent commit which added a source file, and look at what else that commit modified in order to actually compile that source file.

Comment: unfortunately, I could find the commits of chromuim OS not browser! Could you plz give me more information?

Comment: @user32557 I took your question as "I know how to compile Chromium, but I want to pass additional flags. How do I do this?" Does your comment mean you don't know how to compile Chromium yet, or does it mean you're compiling from a release tarball? Either way, https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code has more details.

Comment: @ hvd No! I built chromium from the source code successfully! Now, I am going to add some pieces of my codes to the main source code but I don't know exactly what I should do for that! I couldn't find the commits of Chromium browser.

Comment: @user32557 I was confused because the documented steps should pull the code with full history, so you should already have all the commits readily available locally. But I see now the "If you don't want the full repo history" bit in those steps. If you followed those, you should still be able to re-fetch with history. (Or, if you just prefer a web interface to see the commits, I see it's been mirrored on Github: https://github.com/chromium/chromium/.)